# Spring Authorization Server 1.0.0: javascript error while requesting /oauth2/token

Tags: vue.js, spring-security, oauth, spring-authorization-server

I have created a Spring Authorization Server - you can find the code on github https://github.com/costerutilo/UTILO-Authorization-Server

I can't read the token via javascript. I created a simple Vue web app to get the clients authorization code but I'm not able to to get the token.

Tried it with fetch API:

```
    const url =  'http://127.0.0.1:9000/oauth2/token';

    var credentials = btoa(import.meta.env.VITE_CLIENT_ID + ':' + 'secret');
    var basicAuth = 'Basic ' + credentials;

    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    //myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Basic dXRpbG8tY2xpZW50OnNlY3JldA==");
    myHeaders.append("Authorization", basicAuth);
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
    urlencoded.append("grant_type", "authorization_code");
    // urlencoded.append("code", "yyJTTI3JqNno1XlSW59qxX3CCytMm-ChoHnqVw3iSUGyT6ltT_tpPclQ8bdSyeApO4IWE442irBiRwntJJzae9BIntpC3_vshTgNhAfbsBlkwh3n50jkAxs3hTqavqsy");
    urlencoded.append("code", code);
    urlencoded.append("redirect_uri", "https://www.utilo.eu");

    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: myHeaders,
      body: urlencoded,
      redirect: 'follow'
    };

    fetch(url, requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

In javascript console of the browser I see an CORS exception

```
Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:9000/oauth2/token' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:9010' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check
```

Server Console gives the error:

```
2023-02-27T09:35:53.786+01:00 TRACE 33212 --- [nio-9000-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
```

If I try the same request in Postman I get the JSON with the token.

I don't know what my mistake in reasoning is here or what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to [enable CORS](https://github.com/sjohnr/spring-authorization-server/blob/ef5bcffb516711d0d5b265ed0447f4053a1a3fbd/samples/default-authorizationserver/src/main/java/sample/config/AuthorizationServerConfig.java#L76) for your Spring Security filter chain and provide an `@Bean` such as [this example](https://github.com/sjohnr/spring-authorization-server/blob/bff-demo/samples/default-authorizationserver/src/main/java/sample/config/CorsConfig.java):

```java
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://127.0.0.1:4200");
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return source;
    }

}
```

**Note:** Port `4200` is for an Angular development environment, replace with your Vue dev server port.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Steve!

I added the following code

```
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        //
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
        return urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
    }
```

and in my ajax call I have to add **mode: 'no-cors'**,

```
    const url =  'http://127.0.0.1:9000/oauth2/token';

    let myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
    urlencoded.append("grant_type", "authorization_code");
    urlencoded.append("code", code);
    urlencoded.append("redirect_uri", "http://127.0.0.1:9010/admin");
    urlencoded.append("client_id", "utilo-client");
    urlencoded.append("client_secret", "secret");

    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'no-cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
      headers: myHeaders,
      body: urlencoded,
      redirect: 'follow'
    };

    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:9000/oauth2/token", requestOptions)
        .then((response) => {
          return response.text();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          console.log('data: ' + data); // is empty string???
        })
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Now I no longer get error messages in the Javascript Console and also no more error messages in the Java Console.

But the response from the server is empty. When I test it with Postman I get a correct result. I don't understand what's wrong with that.